# Populating HTML dropdown from databse using with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have followed a tutorial to dynamically populate dropdown using AJAX to the letter. This is my code
config.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
if(!$con){
    die('Could not connect:' .mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('carrental', $con);?>
```

vehicle_dropdown.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT vehicleid,vehiclename FROM tbl_vehicles");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    $data = array();
    while (&row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $row['vehicleid'],
            'name' => $row['vehiclename']
        );    
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}?>
```

Vehicle.php

```
    <?php
    include('config.php');
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Vehicle() {
                $('#vehicledll').empty();
                $('#vehicledll').append("<option>Loading.....</option>");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "vehicle_dropdown.php",
                    contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#vehicledll').empty();
                        $('#vehicledll').append("<option value='0'>--Select Country--</option>");
                        $each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('#vehicledll').append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                Vehicle();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="vehicledll"></select>
    </body>
</html>
```

However  when I run the page the dopdown only displays the message "Loading...."
Please help

Comment: Check the console for errors with the AJAX request. Most likely you have an issue in your PHP code.

Comment: one mistake `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` ... you missed the ';' not sure if that'll fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('#vehicledll').append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
                        });
```

should be

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('#vehicledll').append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
                        });
```

You have missed a `.` after `$`

and `contentType` should be `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: @RayonDabre both can work, `item` is similar to `data[i]` as `i` is the index here.

Comment: Yeah i know but what is the point of accepting second argument if it is not being used..